# NS3 simulation reliable multicast

Tags: simulation, multicast, ns-3

I have a question about how to create a random multicast group for nodes in a network topology.

For example, I have a network topology with 40 nodes, and I want to create five multicast groups. Each group has 5 nodes, and each group has a different multicast address for the host to send the packet to. Below is my code. Thank you to everyone for answering my questions.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_VIZ0u91BtvUQu4Z_DlTMECjI6vF-2Av/view?usp=sharing

The more detailed question is my pleasure